# trying to call join on a worker thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp

I have an onClickListener that uses Okhttp to asynchronously get some stuff in the background. Here's the OnClickListener:

```
mGetChartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String companyName = mSymbolValue.getText().toString();
            getRequest(companyName, "chart");    
            Log.i(TAG, mChartProfile.getSizeDates()+""); // Null exception happens here
    }
});
```

And here is the Okhttp snippet:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request
            .Builder()
            .url(completeUrl)
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    if (requestType.equals("quote")) {
                        isValidSearch = getQuote(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (isValidSearch) {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                                toggleFacts(isValidSearch);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    else{
                        getChartInfo(jsonData);

                    }

                } else {
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "JSONException caught: ", e);
                Toast.makeText(BuyActivity.this, "oops!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (ParseException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to parse", e);
            }
        }
    });
    // How do I do a thread.join() here?

private void getChartInfo(String jsonData) throws JSONException, ParseException{

    JSONObject wholeChartData = new JSONObject(jsonData);

    JSONArray dates = wholeChartData.getJSONArray("Dates");
    mChartProfile = new ChartProfile();
    // ChartProfile contains ArrayList of ChartDate and ArrayList of ChartValue
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length(); i++){
        ChartDate chartDate = new ChartDate(dates.getString(i));
        mChartProfile.addToDates(chartDate);
    }


    JSONArray values = close.getJSONArray("values");

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++){
        ChartValue chartValue = new ChartValue(values.getDouble(i));
        mChartProfile.addToValues(chartValue);
    }
}
```

Right now, I'm getting an error of thread exiting with uncaught exception. And this is caused by a null exception because when calling mChartProfile.getSizeDates(), the values haven't been written in yet. My intuition is that the call to getChartInfo(jsonData) doesn't finish and the main UI thread is already returning from the getRequest() function. Hence, it will continue next line, and try to access an empty array that has not been initialized. Hence, I get a null exception. My solution is to have the main thread wait on the worker thread by calling thread.join() but I am not sure of how to do this through this Okhttp interface. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: you are going to update UI only after 'okHttp` request is complete or you have some data in mChartProfile ? Is it so ?

Comment: mChartProfile only gets set in getChartInfo(). So ideally I would like for getChartInfo to finish, so that I can then access mChartProfile's member variables.

Comment: I dont think it will be a good idea to make the main thread wait for the worker thread to finish and definitly the `ANR` dialog will show up if you do so .

Comment: Ah ok, so I guess I would need another runnable if I were to wait for the worker thread to finish? That makes sense because then the main thread gets blocked and Android will always throw an exception there.

Comment: I would like to suggest a thing or two, initialize `mChartProfile` in `onCreate()` if its an `Activity` or accordingly in a `Fragment`, doing this will solve the NPE, show some sort of `ProgressDialog` until the process is finished, in short a **synchronous** way to handle stuff...